# youtube protocol

Tags: objective-c

i was looking everywhere to find a good guide,or docs about the youtube api for iphone and couldnt find something that answer my needs.

We need to be able to play/stop a youtube videos from our app, NOT from the youtube app,
and to get more metadata such as elapsed time from player .
i also want to be able to fit the player to the specific size that i want, and to be played inside my app and not on explorer or iphone player.

any document ,guide , to that would be great.
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: it doesn't exist.

More complex answer: it could happen, but it'd be a major pain. Basically there would be a few steps you'd need to take:

1. Load the YouTube page into a NSString for regex searching
2. Match the string to find the MP4 URL of the video
3. Create a MPMoviePlayer (or whatever) to play your video
4. ???
5. Profit.

Comment: got you. so basically not :) its strange that ones can not play a simple video from youtube in his app.